# How to define a custom domain?

Tags: resolve

Is there a way in Wolfram language to define a domain by explicitly listing it as a set.

For example given a function `g` as follows:

```
g=Mod[#1+#2,2]&;
```

The following statement

```
Resolve[
    ForAll[a,g[a,0]==a],
    Integers
]
```

is `False` for `a` being an element of `Integers`.

How do I give it a domain `Element[a,{0,1}]`?

---

As pointed out (no pun intended) in the updated answer by `OkkesDulgerci` that `Point[{{0},{1}}]` can be used here, but it fails in the following case.

define additionally inverse function,

```
inv=Mod[#1,2]&;
```

The following statement refuse to resolve

```
ForAll[a,a∈Point[{{0},{1}}],g[a,inv[a]]==0]//Resolve
```

but does resolve with

```
ForAll[a,a∈Integers&&0<=a<=1,g[a,inv[a]]==0]//Resolve
```

So even though `Point[{{0},{1}}]` works in some cases but is failing here!

Comment: `Resolve[ForAll[a, 0 <= a <= 1, g[a, 0] == a], Integers]`?

Comment: @kglr well it is just weird that Wolfram language does not provide a way to define the domain explicitly by listing the elements. Many times it will be not possible or painful to provide a condition to define a subset of the existing domains rather than just listing the values over which to resolve the qualifiers in the statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Update2:** For list type of domain your problems are equivalent to these:

```
dom = {0, 3/2, π};

g = Mod[#1 + #2, 2] &;
inv = Mod[#1, 2] &;
SameQ @@ (g[#1, 0] == #1 & @@@ Cases[Tuples[dom, 2], {_, 0}])
```

> False

```
SameQ @@ (g[#1, inv[#1]] == 0 & @@@ Tuples[dom, 2])
```

> False

**Update:** Adding `Integers` in `Resolve`  solves the problem.

```
g=Mod[#1+#2,2]&;
inv=Mod[#1,2]&;

Resolve[ForAll[a, a ∈ Point[{{0}, {1}}], g[a, inv[a]] == 0], Integers]
```

> True

**Edit:**

> How do I give it a domain Element[a,{0,1}]?

You can use `Point[{{0}, {1}}]` to define the domain explicitly by listing the elements.

```
Resolve[ForAll[a, a ∈ Point[{{0}, {1}}], g[a, 0] == a], Integers]
```

> True

**Original Answer:**

```
Resolve[ForAll[a, Element[a, Integers] && 0 <= a <= 1, g[a, 0] == a]]
```

> True

Or

```
Mod[#1 + #2, 2] == #1 & @@@ Cases[Tuples[{0, 1}, 2], {_, 0}]
```

> {True, True}

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer to give `Point[{{0}, {1}}]` but it is failing in the above case (see my updated question).

Comment: See my update..

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer but the whole point of set defined by explicit listing is to not having to use any predefined domains as reference. What if I am interested in resolving over a set say, `{0, 3/2, π}`.